# Kendo UI DataSource Destroy function calls more than one time for multiple records

Tags: jquery, telerik, kendo-ui

I have a strange problem in Kendo UI - which I dont understand.

This is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var kendo_dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        autoSync: true,
        batch: true,
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "<?php echo BASE_URL . 'kendo/kendo_grid_read' ?>",
                dataType: "json"
            },
            destroy: {
                url: "<?php echo BASE_URL . 'kendo/kendo_grid_destroy' ?>",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST"
            },
            parameterMap: function(data, type) {
                if (type == "destroy") {
                    return {models: data.models}
                }
            }
        },
        serverFiltering: true,
        serverGrouping: true,
        serverPaging: true,
        page: 1,
        pageSize: 5,
        schema: {
            data: "results",
            total: "total",
            model: {
                id: "field1"
            }
        }
    });

    $("#kendo_grid2").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: kendo_dataSource,
        height: 300,
        filterable: true,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: true,
        selectable: "multiple row",
        columns: [
            {
                field: "field1"
            },
            {
                field: "field2"
            },
            {
                field: "field3"
            }
        ]
    });

    $("#test_button").on("click", function() {
        var selectedRows = $("#kendo_grid2").data("kendoGrid").select();
        if (selectedRows.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++) {
                var dataItem = $("#kendo_grid2").data("kendoGrid").dataItem(selectedRows[i]);
                console.log(dataItem);
                kendo_dataSource.remove(dataItem);
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Here goes the situation.

When the `$("#test_button").on("click", function()` is fired, it checks for the selected rows in the grid - and delete the rows.

If I select 2 rows, it deletes 2 rows. And the 2 rows are disappeared from the Grid.

But, I see something strange -

whhen 2 rows are deleted, there is 2 POST request - which is fine.

But the first POST request's parameters are

```
models[0][field1]   3
models[0][field2]   poioioi
models[0][field3]   oiuoiuuigbhkjh
models[0][field4]   kjh kjhkjhyt
```

And the second POST request's parameters are

```
models[0][field1]   3
models[0][field2]   poioioi
models[0][field3]   oiuoiuuigbhkjh
models[0][field4]   kjh kjhkjhyt
models[1][field1]   4
models[1][field2]   kjhk hkiui
models[1][field3]   khkj
models[1][field4]   mkhkhkhkjhghgfgdf
```

And I understand that, I can access the data in the server like this

```
foreach ($_POST['models'] as $model) {
            echo $model['field1'];           
}
```

I was wondering if its possible to send only one request - possibly the second POST request only, as I can delete the 2 rows in one request.

Or sending 2 separate request but with only one model at a time?

Is it possible?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by the `autoSync` setting. When you set it to true the data source calls the `sync` method after every change. Setting `autoSync` to `false` and manually calling the `sync()` method would cause the data source to make only one request with all deleted data items.

Comment: Hi Thank you for the reply, 

I changed the autoSync to false,

And I edited the code like this, 

Just after closing the for loop, I added this line of code

kendo_dataSource.sync();

But I get this error - TypeError: t is undefined

Did I call the sync method at the right spot?

Answer (score 3):

In my case, i manual remove _destroyed data:

**event.sender._destroyed = [];**

```
 var gridOptions = {
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "gettransactions",
                type: "GET"
            },
            destroy: {
                url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "delete",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                type: "POST"
            },
            parameterMap: function (models, operation) {
                if (operation == "destroy" && models)
                    return { models: kendo.stringify(models) };
            }
        },
        requestEnd: function (event) {
            event.sender._destroyed = [];
            grid.data('kendoGrid').refresh();
        },
        schema: {
            data: "listTransaction",
            total: "total",
            model: {
                id: "TransactionCustomerID",
                fields: {
                    TransactionCustomerID: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                    TransactionTime: { type: "date", editable: false }
                }
            },
            errors: "Errors"
        },
        change: function (event, abc) {
            //todo change fucntion              
        },
        serverPaging: false,
        serverFiltering: false,
        error: function (e) {
            console.log("Status: " + e.status + "; Error message: " + e.errorThrown);
        }
    },
    batch: true,
    editable: "popup",
    autoSync: true,
    resizable: true,
    columns: columnOptions,
    sortable: { mode: "single", allowUnsort: true },
    filterable: false,
    pageable: {
        pageSize: 20,
        pageSizes: [20, 50, 100],
        refresh: true
    },
    cancel: function () {
        grid.data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
        grid.data('kendoGrid').refresh();
    },
    dataBound: function (e) {
        hideGridButtonText(".k-delete");
        handleEmptyData(e);
    },
    excel: {
        fileName: "Transaction List.xlsx",
        filterable: true,
        allPages: false,
        downloadElement: "#exportexcel"
    }
};
```

It is working!

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem.

I am using a function for the destroy attribute of the dataSource. My problem was that with each successive deletion of a row, the destroy function was called an additional time in an accumulative manner. This means that for the first deletion the function was called one time, for the second deletion it was called two times, and so on so forth.

In my case, the problem was because of the fact that I was not notifying the dataSource of the successful deletion. Below is the related part of the code from Kendo UI's [documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource). I was missing out the success part.

```
    destroy: function (options) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/products/destroy",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        data: {
          models: kendo.stringify(options.data.models)
        },
        success: function(result) {
          // notify the data source that the request succeeded
          options.success(result);
        },
        error: function(result) {
          // notify the data source that the request failed
          options.error(result);
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I think I have found the origin of the issue.

I subscribed on the datasource error event and I saw an error occured during the JSon parsing (parseerror). So the dataItem is not deleted from the datasource. (that why the datasource is not well synchronized, I was right on this point).

The parseerror occured because my delete webservice returns an empty string.

Now I need to find the way to solve it...

Answer (score 0):

For me it was just setting autoSync to false! Try it.